# Write to same line of file in Python

Tags: python, file, input, output

I'm trying to write a program that generates keys to be used for registering accounts on a game I'm working on.
So far, I have everything working with prints but I'm stuck when trying to write to a file.

This is my current code:

```
import random
file = open('keys.txt', 'w')
chars = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
keys = 0
while keys <= 50:
    for i in range(0,4):
        print(random.choice(chars), end='')
    print('-', end='')
    for i in range(0,4):
        print(random.choice(chars), end='')
    print('-', end='')
    for i in range(0,4):
        print(random.choice(chars), end='')
    print('-', end='')
    for i in range(0,4):
        print(random.choice(chars), end='')
    print('')    
    keys += 1
file.close()
```

To get it to print to the file, I tried adding `file.write(random.choice(chars), end='')` underneath the print in the for loop, however I got a TypeError saying `write() takes no keyword arguments`.

To clarify, the code looked like this:

```
for i in range(0,4):
    print(random.choice(chars), end='')
    file.write(random.choice(chars), end='')
print('-', end='')
```

From searching around I think the problem is to do with the `end=''` in the file.write, but I'm not certain. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your program has a bug. `10` is not a single character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `print` function writes its argument *plus a line end* to the file. Since in some cases you don’t want a line end, you can override this *default parameter* by explicitly saying `print("string", end = '')`.

The `write` function writes only its argument. It does not know about line ends or other magic. Therefore you *must not* pass it such an extra argument.

If your program will live longer, you should structure it to look cleaner. The following code also fixes your “character” `10`, which is really 2 characters.

```
import random
import string

def generateRandomKey():
  alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
  rnd = ''.join(random.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(16))
  return '%s-%s-%s-%s' % (rnd[0:4], rnd[4:8], rnd[8:12], rnd[12:16])

file = open('keys.txt', 'w')
for _ in range(50):
  file.write('%s\n' % generateRandomKey())
file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

*end=""* is a parameter of *print* function, not *write*.

But you can try this one:

```
file.write(str(random.choice(chars))+"\n")
```

Set it to the correct place then it will print them like *print* function.

Comment: Ah, thought that was the problem. How can I print to the same line in a file write then, like `end=''` would in a print function?

Comment: you want to write them abreast?

Comment: `write()` does not append newlines by default.  So, if you want a new line you have explicitly include it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so as I wanted to generate 16 digit keys, I wrote the 4 character blocks to the file with dashes in between, and then I did `file.write('\n')` at the end of the for loop block.

Thanks for your answers everyone, they were very helpful!